# How reinterpret_cast works for flattening a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std, allocator, reinterpret-cast

I would like to represent a `std::vector` of a structure containing several integers as a *"flatten"* vector of integers, **without copying the data**.

I tried something with a `reinterpret_cast` as shown below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Tuple
{
    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    // init
    std::vector<Tuple> vec1(5);
    for(size_t i=0; i<vec1.size(); ++i)
    {
        vec1[i].a = 3 * i + 0;
        vec1[i].b = 3 * i + 1;
        vec1[i].c = 3 * i + 2;
    }   

    // flattening
    std::vector<int>* vec2 = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(&vec1);

    // print
    std::cout << "vec1 (" << vec1.size() << ")  : ";
    for(size_t i=0; i<vec1.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vec1.at(i).a << " " << vec1.at(i).b << " " << vec1.at(i).c << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "vec2 (" << vec2->size() << ") : ";
    for (size_t j = 0; j < vec2->size(); ++j)
    {
        std::cout << vec2->at(j) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which works well since the output is:

```
vec1 (5)  : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
vec2 (15) : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

My questions are :

- Is this behavior compiler dependent? (I am using `g++ 6.3.0`)
- How `vec2` knows that the size of the vector is `15` and not `5`?
- Is their any other solution avoiding the use of `reinterpret_cast`? (If I *"accidentally"* add a `double` member to `Tuple`, the resulting issue could be hard to track...)
- If `vec1` has a specific allocator: `std::vector<Tuple,A<Tuple>>`, what should be the type of `vec2`? `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<int,A<int>>` or `std::vector<int,A<Tuple>>`?

Comment: If you must do things this way you can cast the result of `std::vector::data()` to get a pointer to the first element managed by the vector.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Not guaranteed to be portable, not guaranteed to work.

Comment: You can reinterpret_cast the data() pointer returned from the vector but not the whole vector into another type. And even if you reinterpet_cast only the data pointer it would be portable only if pragma pack is set to 1 else sizeof(struct Tuple) could be greater than 3 * sizeof(int).

Comment: Don't do this. IF you are a beginner you should not be using `reinterpret_cast<>`. This code is just broken and the fact that it works is just a random lucky chance. Changing anything (including compiler flags) could cause it to break.

Comment: @andreaplanet "pragma pack" is not portable. (Knowing that there are no padding bytes doesn't necessarily make it valid to read through a `reinterpret_cast`-ed pointer, either.) The answer is it is not portable, period.

Comment: @aschepler the reinterpret_cast<int*>(vec1.data()) should be portable on compilers that supports packed alignment, specifically, when sizeof(struct Tuple)=3*sizeof(int). If not then why? I'm not suggesting to use such code.

Comment: You asked how it knows that it's 15 rather than 5. While the code is invalid as has been covered elsewhere, that particular bit might be interesting. The vector doesn't store the size, it stores a pointer to the start and end of data and size returns, essentially, end() - begin(). If you want to play with how that ends up working https://godbolt.org/z/B1Uvq4 - change around the types that the pointers are cast to, or the size of the buffer in the struct, and it might become easier to see.

Comment: @andreaplanet It's undefined behavior to use pointer arithmetic when the two pointers don't point at elements of the same array object (or one past the end). Since there is no actual `int[N]` object involved, it's incorrect even to do `&t.a+2`, even if it happens to be that `(char*)&t.c - (char*)&t.a == 2*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't legally reinterpret_cast the entire vector to a different type of vector.  But you can legally cast a pointer to struct to a pointer to the first element of that struct.  So this works:

```
std::vector<Tuple> vec1(5);
int* vec2 = &vec1.front().a;
size_t vec2_size = vec1.size() * sizeof(vec1[0]) / sizeof(vec2[0]);

for (size_t j = 0; j < vec2_size; ++j)
{
    std::cout << vec2[j] << " ";
}
```

You need to make sure there's no padding in `Tuple`, so:

```
static_assert(sizeof(Tuple) == 3 * sizeof(int), "Tuple must be 3 ints");
```

To answer your bulleted questions:

- Is this behavior compiler dependent?

  - Your code was illegal.
- How vec2 knows that the size of the vector is 15 and not 5?

  - You got lucky, your code was illegal.
- Is their any other solution avoiding the use of reinterpret_cast?

  - See above.
- If vec1 has a specific allocator: std::vector>, what should be the type of vec2?

  - Same as above, `int*`.

Comment: "*But you can legally cast a pointer to struct to a pointer to the first element of that struct.*" If you want to get technical, the pointer arithmetic implied by `vec2[j]` is UB, since `vec2` points to a single integer object, not an array of integers. Granted, this will generally still work, but you should still be aware that you're invoking UB.